# Page showing differently in Dreamweaver CS6 vs. Chrome 43.0.2357.124 m

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, dreamweaver

I am a relatively new web designer using Dreamweaver CS6. I am aware that it is best to preview pages in an actual browser and that Dreamweaver's design and live views are only an approximation of the actual code. I usually preview my pages in IE 11 and Chrome.

My web page looks as I wish in design view, but not in live view or in the browsers.

In this case, I want "Academic Book Reviews" to display in Courier New, which it does in design view. However, in Live view and in Chrome itself "Academic Book Reviews" is in Times New Roman despite the h1 CSS command to display in Courier New.

I think this mismatch between DW and Chrome is causing me several problems in many other areas. I am attaching code and screenshots.

Full screen on my desktop is 1920x1200. I am trying to start building a responsive page from 240px and build up with breakpoints at common resolutions.

This is probably something small I am overlooking.

The top is the html in the index file. The bottom is the CSS in the styles.css file.

I have also added an image of how it looks in DW.

Thank you.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Rogers Reviews: Academic Book Reviews</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div ID="wrapper">
        <header="main_header">
            <img src="_images/RR_logo_phone.png" alt="Rogers Reviews logo">
        </header>
        <h1>Academic Book Reviews</h1>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>

   @media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    h1 {
        font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:728px) {
}

@media screen and (min-width:729px) and (max-width:1920px) {
}
```

Here is the link to the image:

http://imgur.com/DhEXfdg

And DW:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkogE.jpg

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that the css at the bottom is in the styles.css file?

Comment: Yes. They are separate. I should have noted that.

Comment: FYI, you can always edit your post to add important info. Also, I'm not seeing a question anywhere in your post, so, what's your question?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Are you sure your browser window is below 320px when you are viewing it? Are you really going to change the font at different break points? If not you shouldn't define it in `@media` break point areas or else you will have to define it at every break point. Put it on a global scope

Comment: At this point I just want the font to be Courier New, which it is not. It remains Times New Roman.

Answer (score 0):

put the h1 tag outside of your media queries unless you want it to only change at a max screen width of 320px :)

```
 h1 {
            font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
        }

@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
    }

}

@media screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:728px) {
}

@media screen and (min-width:729px) and (max-width:1920px) {
}
```

Comment: Ya it would be a maintenance nightmare if you defined the same font style at every break point

Comment: Still shows up as Times. :(

Note that I am not using any kind of CSS reset.

Comment: @Inflames626 if the css is in a css file make sure the path is correct and it's getting imported

Comment: Keep my answer in your css, but we now need to work on your next issue. ok? Are you using an external style sheet?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith a CSS reset is a style sheet that removes all browser default styling. See [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: I thought perhaps some kind of default settings were finding their way into the problem (Times is a common default font).

I avoided using a CSS reset because many of them are very thorough and some are not specific enough. I am not yet experienced enough to be able to customize them to my needs.

I am using XAMPP. Styles location is this:

C:\xampp\htdocs\rogersreviews\styles.css

Comment: then add a class to your h1 like this `<h1 class="font-1"></h1>` that way you can set individual styles like `h1.font-1{some style here}`

Comment: Tried to add the class. Still not working. Very strange. The CSS and HTML are connected in Dreamweaver (both are in the root folder).

Comment: Also note that the HTML file found the file in the _images folder, so the directory structure seems to be okay.

Courier New is also a font present on my machine.

Styles and media queries in DW both point to C:\xampp\htdocs\rogersreviews\styles.css

Comment: So it seems this is going to be a dreamweaver specific issue, since you are running it locally on your machine. Probably a dreamweaver guy can help you. Sorry- I tried.

Comment: actually, add `#wrapper{background-color: black;}` to the top of your css if it changes colors then we know for sure you have your path right.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith, thanks much. Learning about the headings outside the media queries was enough (I considered MQ's to be basically repeating the entire CSS stylesheet over and over with only the percentages altered).

Perhaps DW needs to be patched?

Anyway, it is good practice for me to spot small problems.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith, it changes to black in DW but not in Chrome.

Comment: can you show me your file paths for both the css and html?

Comment: Allow me to patch my version of DW CS6 to 12.0.3 and I will get back with all of you.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith C:\xampp\htdocs\rogersreviews

Both styles.css and index.php are in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by switching DW's file associations from document root to site root.

The changes everyone suggested are now taking effect in Chrome.

Thank you everyone for your help and for your hospitality to a newbie (some SO folks can be a bit snarky :) ).